# How do I allow a standard user on my Windows 10 PC to run the installed anti-virus program without the UAC prompting for an admin password?

Tags: windows-10, uac

I have a standard user account for my younger brother and every time he plugs in a USB pen drive, the anti-virus program triggers a scan (as expected) but the UAC prompts him to key in the admin password. I never had this happen with previous Windows versions. He is unable to run the scan without the password.

I do not wish to disable the UAC and would like to know if there is a way around this problem.

Comment: You install the software in question as an Administrator I assume?

Comment: The software in question has been already installed by me from my admin account. The issue is that it is requiring admin password when a standard user tries to run it.